# Adding user to chroot environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chroot, debootstrap

I've created a chroot system in my Ubuntu using schroot and debrootstrap, based on minimal ubuntu. However whenever I can't seem to add a new user into this chroot environment. Here is what happens.

1. I enter schroot as root and add a new user.(Tried both adduser and useradd commands)
2. The username lists up in /etc/passwd file and I can 'su' into the new user. So far so good.
3. When I log out of schroot, and re-enter schroot, the user I created has vanished!! There is no mention of that user in /etc/passwd either.

How do I make the new user permanent?

Comment: This sounds strange. First try to be sure that the directories are correct, both when you're inside the chroot and outside. Then, do `cat /etc/passwd` after creating the user, then log out, and `cat` the same file, now with chroot directory prefixed. Did it change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I figured it out myself. Schroot has a feature called "sessions" where current environment can be preserved. Everytime one logs out without creating a "session", schroot brings everything to clean state and hence deletes the user as well. 
One can start a session using

```
schroot -c mychroot -b
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, but note that anyway the users won't persist after system reboot. I added an answer which seems to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a better workaround, that I found it [schroot FAQ](http://linux.die.net/man/7/schroot-faq), in section **Why is schroot overwriting configuration files in the chroot?**

> By default, schroot copies over the system NSS databases ('passwd',
> 'shadow', 'group', 'gshadow', 'services', 'protocols', 'networks', and
> 'hosts', etc.) into the chroot. The reason for this is that the chroot
> environment is not a completely separate system, and it copying them
> over keeps them synchronised. However, this is not always desirable,
> *particularly if installing a package in the chroot creates system
> users and groups which are not present on the host, since these will
> disappear next time the databases are copied over*.

**In short:** each time you start a new schroot session, or after host system reboot, schroot grabs `/etc/passwd` and some other files from you real system and copies them into chroot, thus losing all new users from it. The suggested workaround is described in this FAQ: you can disable copying this files:

1. Open `/etc/schroot/default/nssdatabases` (on your real system, of course)
2. You will see the lis of so called [NSS databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch), that are copied from real system.
3. Comment lines `passwd`, `group` and `shadow`, so that the file looks like this:

#### /etc/schroot/default/nssdatabases

```
# System databases to copy into the chroot from the host system.
#
# <database name>
#passwd
#shadow
#group
services
protocols
networks
hosts
```

Now if you go back inside your chroot and create some users, or install some postgresql etc, new users won't be lost. Even after reboot!